# Null Pointer Exception on Query Inventory

Tags: javascript, android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to set up in-app billing in my application. I have it in alpha testing. I keep getting crash reports from all my testers with the same logcat, shown here:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  
ComponentInfo{autonote.six.padc.autonote/autonote.six.padc.autonote.SaveScreen}:     
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at autonote.six.padc.autonote.SaveScreen.onCreate(SaveScreen.java:59)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
... 11 more
```

It seems like a simple solution, just go to Line Line 59, right? Wrong. When I go there, the line that is throwing the exception is:

```
 mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
```

And this is where I lose it. 
Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
public class SaveScreen extends ActionBarActivity {
Button EMAIL_NOTES;
IabHelper mHelper;
String UPGRADE_CODE = "upgrade_autonote";
public static int VERSION_NUMBER = 534985739;
boolean mIsPremium;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_savescreen);
    //Query Inventory to see if user is premium
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener
            = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                             Inventory inventory) {

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // handle error here
            }
            else {
                // does the user have the premium upgrade?
                mIsPremium = inventory.hasPurchase(UPGRADE_CODE);
                VERSION_NUMBER = 434975736;
            }
        }
    };
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^null pointer^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


    EMAIL_NOTES.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(VERSION_NUMBER == 534985736){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You must upgrade to unlock this feature", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else if(VERSION_NUMBER == 434975739){
                Intent EMAIL_NOTES = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Email_Notes.class);
                EMAIL_NOTES.putExtra("serialized",cNotes_serialized);
                EMAIL_NOTES.putExtra("class_Name", cName);
                startActivity(EMAIL_NOTES);



            }
        }
    });
```

}
Any ideas how to fix this issue? For the record I already went in and bought the product. It said the purchase was successful. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

here:

> mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);

NPE because  `mHelper` is `null`.

Initialize `mHelper` object by calling `IabHelper` constructor with current Acitivty context and with public key:

```
mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
```

For more information `What is base64EncodedPublicKey?` see:

[Preparing Your In-app Billing Application](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html)

Comment: Ok, I did this. Now I am getting an error saying `java.lang.IllegalStateException: IAB helper is not set up. Can't perform operation: queryInventory`  within the same class. Any more ideas?